# "Cool" ways of getting Negative Numbers with a Rearrangement of the Alternating Harmonic Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

I was trying to find a rearrangement of the alternating harmonic series $$(1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 \cdots)$$ that would sum to a negative number.

**First Question**: What is your favorite way or just a cool way to do this? I think my way is cool because it uses an inequality which I think is kind of cool, as I will explain below.

My way:

We start with $1 - \frac12 - \frac14 - \frac16 - \frac18$ (which is negative), and then for each natural number $k$ ($0$ is not a natural number), we add these six terms

$$\frac{1}{(2k+1)} - \sum_{n=5k}^{5k+4}\frac{1}{2n}$$

which turns out to always be negative (this is the "cool" inequality that I mentioned earlier). In this way, all terms of the original series are represented, so it's a valid rearrangement, and the infinite sum either converges to some negative number or diverges to $- \infty$.

I thought the inequality was surprisingly simple because I didn't expect that 5 consecutive even reciprocals would be sufficient to make the above sum negative **for every natural number $k$**. I guess it's not super surprising though since $\frac15(\frac{1}{2k+1})$ is smaller than the first three negative terms, and it's bigger than only the last two terms.

Another reason I found it to be cool is because the sum is kind of like a greedy algorithm. Start with the first positive number, $1$, then add the negative numbers in order until this group of terms is negative. Then go to the next positive number, $\frac13$, and take the next available negative numbers in order until this group of terms is negative. And so on, and so on.

Anyways, in order to figure out that the above was always negative, I plugged it into Wolfram alpha and found the coefficients were all negative (see pic below).

**Second Question**: Is there a better way to show that this is always negative than simply multiplying it out? I mean multiplying it out works, but it is tedious and not very insightful, in my opinion.

Thank you for your time and for your thoughts!

[image: Wolfram Alpha Computation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second question: The convexity of the function $\frac1{2x}$ implies that the average of two of its values at $x_1$ and $x_2$ is greater than the value at the midpoint of $x_1$ and $x_2$; in particular,
\begin{align*}
\frac1{2(5k+1)} + \frac1{2(5k+3)} > 2\cdot \frac1{2(5k+2)} \\
\frac1{2(5k)} + \frac1{2(5k+4)} > 2\cdot \frac1{2(5k+2)}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2k+1} - \sum_{n=5k}^{5k+4}\frac{1}{2n} &< \frac1{2k+1} - (2+2+1)\frac1{2(5k+2)} \\
&= -\frac{1}{2 (2 k+1) (5 k+2)} < 0.
\end{align*}

For the first question: it is known that any real number can be realized as the sum of a suitable rearrangement of any conditionally convergent series. For the alternating harmonic series, there's even an algorithmic way to do so—see [page 27 of these slides](https://www.math.iupui.edu/~ccowen/ButlerAHslides.pdf) for example. That theorem actually shows that the sum of the rearrangement you describe is exactly equal to $-\frac12\log\frac54$.

Comment: Thank you so much! The answer makes sense, and the slides give a very easy to understand and intuitive exposition!